# Database on Cloud

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cloud, google-cloud-platform, web-development-server

BACKGROUND-
I am planning to make a website that will accept data from users to store them in a database(MySQL).The website would be served from google cloud servers.I have installed MAMP on my mac for web development.
PROBLEM-
Google cloud services also provide Cloud SQL.Now I have a few doubts-
1)Once I finish designing my website on MAMP and want to deploy it on cloud servers I would have database settings of my local machine.Does this mean that before putting it on cloud and in order to use Cloud SQL as database I would have to change code on back-end side that specifies database settings?If yes then how tedious is it to do so?(Changing database from testing environment from MySQL to deployment environment Cloud SQL).
2)Also is there a way to use cloud and not use Cloud SQL?
3)What else combination can be chosen with database to deploy website on cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Usually changing the database needs huge efforts(testing and some config changes) as all the databases provide many additional features which doesn't work directly on another database.

You can use Cloud(Cloud SQL is just part of it).
But the Cloud SQL is mysql only as per the information given on the below link by google
https://cloud.google.com/products/

So, it should not be a big deal for you to migrate the project to cloud from your local system. Only you have to configure the connection details(it will not be simply localhost).